# PHP GET URL local domain

Tags: php, redirect

I have redirect page called get.php which contain the following code:

```
  header('Location: '.urldecode($_GET['url']));
  $url = (isset($_GET[url]) && !empty($_GET[url])) ? $_GET[url] : NULL;
  if(empty($url)){
  header('Location: http://www.example.com/404');
}
```

This link used for ref tracking. When I check logs, I found someone abused it with pointing to non-malware website ie.

```
http://www.example.com/get.php?s&url=http://i-am-malware.yes
```

How to prevent this abused and only accept within local domain.

Comment: Prepend it with your domain name. PS: not sure why you use `urldecode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
$url = "";
if(isset($_GET['url']))
{
    $url = urldecode($_GET['url']);

}

if($url=="")
{
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/404');
    exit;
}
else
{
    $arr = parse_url($url);
    if($arr['host']==$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])
    {
        header("Location:".$url);
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location: http://www.example.com/404');
    }
    exit;   
}
```